# How can I use Android DataBinding to dynamically change android:layout property?

Tags: java, android, layout, data-binding

I have the **XML** layout code:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="info" type="com.mycompany.orm.binders.MyBinderObject"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:gravity="end">

    ...
```

And this works great. However, I have a property inside `MyBinderObject` called `mygravity`, and it is set to one of two strings: `start` or `end`. I am trying to figure out how to read the **Data Binding** property `mygravity` to assign the gravity to the layout.

I.e., `android:gravity="@{info.mygravity}"` (However, this line does not work. The compile-time databinding code fails).

**Does anyone have an idea how to dynamically set the `android:gravity` based on a Data-bound objects property?**

Comment: "and it is set to one of two strings" -- `android:gravity` does not take a string. It takes one of a set of enumerated attribute values. My guess is that you will need to convert that string to [the equivalent `Gravity` constant](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html).

Comment: Yup! That was it. I didn't realize that `gravity` was actually an enumerated attribute. Put this in an answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a property inside MyBinderObject called mygravity, and it is set to one of two strings: start or end.

Therein lies the problem: you're doing something reasonable and treating the layout XML like XML.

The layout XML attribute values can be of a variety of types. Sometimes, this is obvious, such as `android:enabled="false"` or `android:layout_width="30sp"`. And, sometimes, the type really is a string or string resource reference (e.g., `android:text="Foo"`). But sometimes the attribute value looks like an English-language string, but it is really one of a set of enumerated values (e.g., gravity values).

> I didn't realize that gravity was actually an enumerated attribute

A rough-cut rule of thumb: if the build would fail if you translated the value into another language, then it is an enumerated attribute (e.g., `android:gravity="fin"` instead of `android:gravity="end"`, assuming that Google Translate gave me reasonable Spanish there...). If the translated value would work just fine, then it's any valid string or (usually) string resource.

> I am trying to figure out how to read the Data Binding property mygravity to assign the gravity to the layout.

You will have to transmogrify the string values into equivalent `Gravity` constants like `Gravity.START`.

Answer (score -1):

you can definitely use `android:gravity="@{info.mygravity}"` in layout file but make sure that mygravity should be int value.

you should refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)

like if you want `center` gravity, value of `info.mygravity` should be `Gravity.CENTER`